# Update Sheet values from another sheet using win32com

Tags: python, win32com

[image]

I want to update sheet1 with Sheet3 data using win32com, Expectation is that when Sheet3 data is changed Sheet1 data needs to be updated automatically

Comment: Why not just use Excel's built in data check? Also, this is not just a problem for win32com, you also need to make a script than continuously runs in the background and checks the file, which only works on saved files, so it wont work while you're changing data in real time without saving.
Also - where is your attempt?

Comment: As i am using win32com to update/create sheets i wanted to add the formulas to cell using win32com only. I don't think there will be a need of script to run continuously as the expectation is when data changes in one sheet, other sheet should be changed.